# How to embed book viewer in Flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I am trying to use the Google Books API to embed a book preview viewer in my Flutter app. The API is designed for web developers, so I started by installing the "flutter webview plugin", and also "webview flutter". I have tried to adapt several examples (mainly [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-book-scanning-app-displaying-book-information--mobile-17880) and [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/loading-local-assets-in-webview-in-flutter-b95aebd6edad)), but to no avail.

So what I want is an embedded book viewer that fits exactly the dimensions of my screen and is not moveable within the webview. The only way I can see is by using the JavaScript code provided by the API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//books.google.com/books/previewlib.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
GBS_insertEmbeddedViewer('ISBN:0738531367',600,500);
</script>
```

The question is: can it be done? And if so, what's the best way of going about it? Or is there a way of converting the JS code to Dart?

Comment: Have you tried [dart-lang](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis) version? I don't know anything about Google Books API, but Google did make a dart version, so I think you might not need to fight with javascript.

Comment: Yes, I've been using this for the other parts of the app, but the embedding does not appear to be covered by the doc... Not sure why...